# prevent spacing on sides when creating css ticker

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am creating a news ticker but am having issues showing it in a continuous loop. As you can see from the [code sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-butterfly-w620o) there is gaps on both sides of the ticker at the beginning and at the end. Perhaps it isn't possible to do this in pure css? and maybe I need to use js to manipulate the array. Can anyone give me any guidance on the approach I should take?

I am talking about the blue gap on the right and left at the beginning and end of the animation

[image]

```
import styled, { keyframes } from "styled-components";

const customTicker = keyframes`
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(1000%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(-1000%, 0, 0);
  }
`;

const CryptosWrapper = styled.div`
  background: #123962;
  overflow: hidden;
`;

const TickerWrap = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
`;

const CryptoWrapper = styled.div`
  color: white;
  flex: 1 0 100px;
  animation: ${customTicker} 7s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
`;

const Currency = styled.span`
  color: #5d81a6;
`;

const Heading = styled.p`
  font-size: 12px;
`;

function App() {
  const [cryptos, setCryptos] = React.useState(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://api.coincap.io/v2/assets")
      .then(res => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(res => {
        setCryptos(res.data.slice(0, 10));
      });
  }, []);
  return (
    <CryptosWrapper>
      <TickerWrap>
        {cryptos &&
          cryptos.map(crypto => {
            return (
              <CryptoWrapper key={crypto.id}>
                <Heading>{crypto.symbol}/USD</Heading>
                <p>
                  {parseFloat(crypto.priceUsd)
                    .toFixed(2)
                    .toLocaleString("en-US")}{" "}
                  <Currency>USD</Currency>
                </p>
              </CryptoWrapper>
            );
          })}
      </TickerWrap>
    </CryptosWrapper>
  );
}
```

Comment: If I understood correctly and you want the ticker sides to not have margin between page, all you need to do is add css rule: `body { margin: 0; }`

Comment: nope, I mean the big empty blue space once the ticker has come to the end of it's run. I wish it was just `margin: 0` 

Comment: Can you please attach an image explaining what you want to remove?

Comment: attached - see updated question ☝️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick solution, which is somewhat of a hard-coded solution. Imo, there are more robust solutions that will be easier to maintain.

The issue with the current implementation is we don't have an infinite supply of content. We need to have an infinite loop of ticker symbols, so the last ticker symbol is immediately followed by the first ticker symbol.

A quick way to achieve this is to duplicate the ticker symbols. Something like:

```
setCryptos([...res.data.slice(0, 10), ...res.data.slice(0, 10)]);
```

This gives us a continuous stream of symbols, like:

```
A B C D E A B C D E
```

Now we can tweak the animation loop so it restarts at exactly the moment the 2nd starting symbol `A` reaches the same position as the 1st `A`, with a small tweak to the keyframes:

```
const customTicker = keyframes`
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(-1000%, 0, 0);
  }
`;
```

And here's the result:

```js
const customTicker = window.styled.keyframes`
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
    visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-1000%);
  }
`;

const CryptosWrapper = window.styled.div`
  background: #123962;
  overflow: hidden;
`;

const TickerWrap = window.styled.div`
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
`;

const CryptoWrapper = window.styled.div`
  color: white;
  flex: 1 0 100px;
  animation: ${customTicker} 7s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
`;

const Currency = window.styled.span`
  color: #5d81a6;
`;

const Heading = window.styled.p`
  font-size: 12px;
`;

function App() {
  const [cryptos, setCryptos] = React.useState(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://api.coincap.io/v2/assets")
      .then(res => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(res => {
        setCryptos([...res.data.slice(0, 10), ...res.data.slice(0, 10)]);
      });
  }, []);
  return (
    <CryptosWrapper>
      <TickerWrap>
        {cryptos &&
          cryptos.map(crypto => {
            return (
              <CryptoWrapper key={crypto.id}>
                <Heading>{crypto.symbol}/USD</Heading>
                <p>
                  {parseFloat(crypto.priceUsd)
                    .toFixed(2)
                    .toLocaleString("en-US")}{" "}
                  <Currency>USD</Currency>
                </p>
              </CryptoWrapper>
            );
          })}
      </TickerWrap>
    </CryptosWrapper>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/styled-components/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Just a quick question, which approach would be better than the hard coded solution you provided?

Answer (score -1):

As if superfluous. Why don't you use [marquee](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee)?

Comment: first line on the link you provided - Obsolete
This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it.